Android: Two views on opposite side without overlap taking as little space as their content
I have a very simple yet frustrating issue:
I have two views inside a layout. The layout can be any layout but I have been trying to use a ConstraintLayout.
I want these two views on opposite sides like below:
Like this:
I want the views:

on opposite sides
texts to wrap if they don't fit
shouldn't overlap
taking up as little space as needed so that click actions aren't triggered by clicking the empty space

This is the code:
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/view2"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

I have tried searching StackOverflow but no questions handle all the scenarios I have listed. Help please.
In all my different attempts, I haven't been able to get all 4 needs met

I thinks this is what you are looking for.
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/a_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="This is view 1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/a_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="This isa long text in view 2" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/a_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


This is the result:


I have done this type design in one of my project, please check below code.
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!-- Left TextView -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Left View"
        android:maxLines="2"  <!-- Ensures text wraps if needed -->
        android:ellipsize="end"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp" />

    <!-- Right TextView -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Right View"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp" />
        
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


I tried this but only the left view wraps with this. The right view takes up full length and keeps squeezing the left view.
